# Get current user instead of new

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

After a lot of work I've (kinda of) figured out how to create a relation between 2 spring entities and I can now create a record of that in my join table. Currently I send a movie object from my Angular framework to my Spring API.

```
createMovie(movie: Movie): void {
  this._dataService.createMovie<Movie>({'name': 'Star Wars'})
  .subscribe((data) => this.movies.push(data),
  error => () => {
      'something went wrong';
  },
  () => {
      // console.log(this.movies);
  });
}
```

My MovieController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Movie createMovie(@RequestBody Movie movie){
    return movieService.createMovie(movie);
}
```

My MovieService.java:

```
@Override 
public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {

    Date date = new Date();

    movieRepository.save(movie);

    userRepository.save(new HashSet<User>(){{
        add(new User("zxc@cvb.nl", "asd", "zxc", true, "123qwe", date, "cxv", new HashSet<Movie>(){{
            add(movie);
        }}));
    }});

    return movieRepository.save(movie);
}
```

And the MovieRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends CrudRepository<Movie, Serializable> {}
```

The main problem with this code is that I instantiate a new User object when I add the movie. This results in the following error:

> Duplicate entry 'cxv' for key 'UK_sb8bbouer5wak8vyiiy4pf2bx'

How do refactor the code so I don't have to instantiate a new user, but I can use my current user?

Comment: You need to query for user and only create it if it is not in database. That needs to be done before userRepository.save(new HashSet<User>() call and if user exists set movie on it and pass that one instead of new User.

Comment: Also, instead of defining a new inner class every time you need a set, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-

Comment: Should I send the user object from the front-end? Or should I try to get the user object through the back-end?

Comment: With this information I've figured out how to get the current user object in the needed controller. http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security